# Success feedback for debounce updates

Tags: forms, input, validation

When creating a form that updates automatically after a short debounce time (thus without a save button), is it best to provide a visual feedback if the update was saved successfully and in case of an update error or is it ok to just display a message if an error occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I think about forms, I would say most forms do have a submit or save button. Hence most users probably expect that in your form to.

To give the user the security that the inputs are saved I would go with a visual feedback, that the data is saved. This could be something like a small text like "all changes saved" or similar.
If there is an error think about giving the user instructions on what to do in order not to loose the data. If no instructions are given, users will try to fix it probably by refresh the page and loose the data which might be quite frustrating.

You probably should test your design on users. If the users expect a save button, you probably should provide them one. You could use this save button to communicate that it is already saved...